# how to append nested file id while submitting a templete driven form in angular 8?

Tags: angular, spring, typescript, spring-boot, rest

I am new in angular. I am facing an issue where I am submitting a form which contain file upload.
File upload is file.
While submitting the form, studentImage is missing.
Need help to append the file id in form data? I just want to pass studentImage id to form data.

This is my rest api which I am consuming here:

```
{
    "studentName": "xyz",
    "studentCurrentStatus": "Studying in DU",
    "studentFeedback": "abcabc abc",
    "studentBatch": "2019",
    "studentImage": {
        "id": 1
    }
}
```

---

```
 onSelectFile(event) {
    const file = event.target.files[0];
    console.log(file);
    this.userProfile = file;
  }

  uploadFile() {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', this.userProfile);
    this.fileService.saveFile(formData).subscribe((res) => {
      console.log(res);
      // const responseJSON = JSON.parse(res);
      this.imageId = res.id;
      console.log(this.imageId);
    });
  }

  saveNewTestimonial(item: Testimonial) {

    console.log(this.testimonial);
    const formData = new FormData();

    formData.append('studentImage', this.imageId);
    this.testimonialService.saveTestimonial(formData)
      .subscribe((response) => {
        console.log(response);
      });
```

Form:

```
  <h1>Add Student Testimonial</h1>
    <form >

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="studentName">Student's Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="studentName" required>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="studentBatch">Student's Batch</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="studentBatch">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="studentCurrentStatus">Student's Current Status</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="studentCurrentStatus">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="studentFeedback">Student's Feedback</label>
        <textarea type="text" class="form-control" id="studentFeedback"></textarea>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="studentImage">Student's Photo</label>
        <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="studentImage" accept="image/*" (change)="onSelectFile($event)" #fileInput>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" (click)="uploadFile()">Upload File</button>
      </div>

      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" (click)="saveNewTestimonial(testimonial)">Submit</button>

    </form>
```